# Azure yaml - line break character support

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have long running lines in my azure devops yaml file such as

```
condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['SomeStep.IsScheduledBuild'], 'True'), eq(variables['userOverride.Setting1'], 'yes'), .......))
```

What is the line break character for such long running conditions so that the yml file conditions such as above can be placed neatly in multiple lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What is the line break character

It should be `|`.

Please refer to below yaml:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  condition: |
   and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['SomeStep.IsScheduledBuild'], 'True'),
   eq(variables['userOverride.Setting1'], 'yes')))
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo Write your commands here
      echo Hello world
```

Put a `|` after `condition:` then you can seperate the expression to multiple lines.

Comment: what if I want to break at `and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['SomeStep.IsScheduledBuild'], 'True'),`

Comment: Where do you want to break at?  .IsScheduledBuild'],(HERE?) 'True'? If so, i have tested it and it works as expected.